# Is there any way to navigate with useNavigation hook to a class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-navigation

Is there any way to navigate with useNavigation hook to a class component ?

This is my class:

`export default class AzureLogin extends React.Component`

So i need to navigate to the `AzureLogin` from `Screen1`  .
what is the way to do it ?

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Screen1 = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userState = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer);

  const [isSync, setIsSync] = useState(false);
  const syncData = useGetUserDevicesData(isSync);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (syncData.isLoaded === true) {
      setIsSync(false);
      setData(syncData.data);
    }
  }, [syncData.isLoaded]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getItem = async () => {
      const azureToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AZURE-TOKEN');
      const userName = await AsyncStorage.getItem('AZURE-USERNAME');
      const googlToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('GOOGLE-TOKEN');
      const deviceId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('DEVICE-ID');
      const platformId = await AsyncStorage.getItem('PLATFORM-TYPE');

      getSaveUserTokenData({
        userName,
        googlToken,
        platformId,
        deviceId,
        azureToken,
      });
    };
    getItem();
  }, []);

  const getSaveUserTokenData = async (data) => {
const navigation = useNavigation();

    const url =
      'https://' +
      'userName=' +
      data.userName +
      '&userToken=' +
      data.googlToken +
      '&PlatformType=' +
      data.platformId +
      '&DeviceID=' +
      data.deviceId;
    await fetch(url, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Authorization: data.azureToken,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        console.log(
          'THE FETCH DATA TO getSaveUserTokenData FUNCTION IS:',

          data
        );
      })
      .catch((error) => {}); //**HERE I NEED TO NAVIGATE !!**
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Being able to navigate a screen doesn't depend on whether it is a functional or a class component. So you can navigate to AzureLogin of course.

But as #1 [Rules of Hooks](https://en.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) clearly states

> **Only Call Hooks at the Top Level**

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.
> Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By
> following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same
> order each time a component renders. That’s what allows React to
> correctly preserve the state of Hooks between multiple useState and
> useEffect calls. (If you’re curious, we’ll explain this in depth
> below.)

So, based on your Screen1 component,

You should move your `useNavigation` hook from `getSaveUserTokenData` to the top level like below:

```
const Screen1 = (props) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState('');
  const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const userState = useSelector((state) => state.userReducer);
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  ...
```

Only then, you can call `navigation.navigate('AzureLogin')` inside wherever you want.